# Cannot start the debugger for the ruby program with Aptana Studio 3 in Windows

Tags: ruby, aptana, aptana3, ruby-debug

As the title of this question, I cannot start debugging my `rb` file in Aptana Studio 3. This is the output of the "Console" view:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find ruby-debug-base (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.2.1, actionpack-3.2.1, activemodel-3.2.1, activerecord-3.2.1, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.1, activeresource-3.2.1, activesupport-3.2.1, archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2, arel-3.0.2, bigdecimal-1.1.0, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.0.22, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.2.0, columnize-0.3.6, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-1.3.0, fastthread-1.0.1-x86-mswin32, gem_plugin-0.2.3, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, io-console-0.3, journey-1.0.2, json-1.5.4, linecache-0.43-x86-mswin32, linecache19-0.5.12, mail-2.4.1, mime-types-1.17.2, minitest-2.5.1, mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60, multi_json-1.1.0, mysql-2.7.3-x86-mswin32, pg-0.13.1-x86-mingw32, polyglot-0.3.3, rack-1.4.1, rack-cache-1.1, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.2.1, railties-3.2.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rb-readline-0.4.2, rbx-require-relative-0.0.9, rdoc-3.9.4, ruby-debug-base-0.10.3-x86-mswin32, ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre10, ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta16, ruby-debug-ide-0.4.5, ruby_core_source-0.1.5, rubyzip-0.9.6.1, sprockets-2.1.2, sqlite3-1.3.5-x86-mingw32, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, tiny_tds-0.5.1-x86-mingw32, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.31] (Gem::LoadError)
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:435:in `find_by_name'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:206:in `try_activate'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `rescue in require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta16/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `require_relative'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta16/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `<main>'
```

I have checked and I don't understand why it does not find `ruby-debug-base`. This the output of `gem list --local`

```
actionmailer (3.2.1)
actionpack (3.2.1)
activemodel (3.2.1)
activerecord (3.2.1)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.1)
activeresource (3.2.1)
activesupport (3.2.1)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.22)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
columnize (0.3.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.0)
fastthread (1.0.1 i386-mswin32)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.2)
json (1.5.4)
linecache (0.43 mswin32)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.4.1)
mime-types (1.17.2)
minitest (2.5.1)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mswin32-60)
multi_json (1.1.0)
mysql (2.7.3 mswin32)
pg (0.13.1 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.1)
railties (3.2.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (3.9.4)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.3 mswin32)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta16, 0.4.5)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubyzip (0.9.6.1)
sprockets (2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.5 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
tiny_tds (0.5.1 x86-mingw32)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
```

My ruby enviroment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.16
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/TrungHieu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I have used **RailsInstaller 2.1.0** to install my ruby.

Can anyone help me to make the debugger wotk.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the "server" tab using Window->show view and then use it for your specific app. I got it working with the fast-debugger (user gem debugger in your gemfile) and you are good to go.

https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger